# How to set Breakpoints in JavaScript? - Chrome’s developer tools

Tags: javascript

I want to set a break in a function placed in the `<body>` section of an website.

I can interrupt that flow control from Chrome’s developer tools or whatever other tool?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function () {
        Break?
        //Code
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

set `debugger;` within your script, open console..and refresh page .
ie.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Before');
    debugger;
    console.log('After');
    var a=1;
    var b=2;
    var c=a+b;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/3umzsLqL/

Answer (score 0):

Use `debugger`:

```
function(){ 
    debugger
    // break point
}
```